# How to extract colnames in using quantmod function downloaded data(stock price)

Tags: r, extract

I used this code and package `quantmod`, to download Microsoft stock price info.

I want to make colname(date) to one data. I would like to extract colnames.

Now

```
colname    |    MSFT

2010-01-23 | 304.1
```

After

```
colname  | date       | MSFT
1        | 2010-01-23 | 304.1
2        | 2010-01-24 | 303.3
3        | 2010-01-25 | 301.6
```

```
library(quantmod)
MSFT<-getSymbols(Symbols = "MSFT",
                 from = '2007-01-01', 
                 to = '2018-12-31', 
                 auto.assign = FALSE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate: What library you are referring to, and in short what does it do. Also: please be more specific as to what you are asking.

Comment: i want to using quantmod fackage dowenlod data and make excel, downloaded row data like NOW i wanna make like AFTER form